# spring boot data only support solrj5.5?

Tags: spring-boot, version, solrj

At present,i use **solr 7.1**,and want to integrate with **spring boot** ,but likely spring boot and solrj the highest version of the support is 5.5.but i use solr 7.1,and HttpSolrServer of solr is deprecated. Is it possible to perform the integration using solr 7.1

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to upgrade individual versions of specifics libraries in spring-boot.

There is a file in spring boot that manages all it's preset versions found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

```
<solr.version>5.5.5</solr.version>
```

You could try overwrite this version by overwriting it in **your own pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <solr.version>7.1</solr.version>
</properties>
```

but beware this might break other stuff.